# Paginating Microsoft SQL and PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

Did an attempt at it earlier today, however i have re-done the script and i got it partial working, however it just shows the latest 2 posts on all pages (just two pages atm cuz there is only 4 blog posts) so what the F am i missing here?

```
<?php
$rowsPerPage = 2;
try
{
$conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=localhost ; Database=blog", "******", "*********");
 $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
}
catch(Exception $e)
{ 
die( print_r( $e->getMessage() ) ); 
}

try
{
$tsql = "SELECT COUNT(blogID) FROM blog_posts";

$stmt = $conn->query($tsql);

$rowsReturned = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

if($rowsReturned[0] == 0)
{
    echo "No rows returned.";
}
else
{     
    $numOfPages = ceil($rowsReturned[0]/$rowsPerPage);
    for($i = 1; $i<=$numOfPages; $i++)
    {
        $pageNum = "index.php?pageID=$i";
        print("<a href=$pageNum>$i</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;");
    }
    echo "<br/><br/>";
}

$tsql = "SELECT * FROM 
            (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY blogID desc) 
                         AS RowNumber, 
                            blog_title,    
                            blog_post,
                            blog_author,
                            blog_category,
                            blog_date
         FROM blog_posts)
         AS Temp
         WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN ? AND ?";

$stmt2 = $conn->prepare($tsql);

if(isset($_GET['pageNum']))
{
    $highRowNum = $_GET['pageNum'] * $rowsPerPage;
    $lowRowNum = $highRowNum - $rowsPerPage + 1;
}
else
{
    $lowRowNum = 1;  
    $highRowNum = $rowsPerPage;
}

$params = array(&$lowRowNum, &$highRowNum);

$stmt2->execute(array($lowRowNum, $highRowNum));

while($row = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM) )
{
         echo " $row[0]"; 
           echo "<h2 style=text-align:center>", $row[1],"</h2>"; 
           echo "$row[2]"; 
           echo "$row[3]"; 
           echo "$row[4]"; 
           echo date_format( new DateTime($row['5']), 'd M y, H:i' ); 
}
}
catch(Exception $e)
{ 
die( print_r( $e->getMessage() ) ); 
}
?>
```

and lastly is it much more work to include pagination for my blog categorys aswell in the script? i get kinda blind when scripts grow below 15 lines hah

Comment: `?pageID` and you're doing `$_GET['pageNum']`. I'd call that `undefined...` and probably relying on `$pageNum`. It doesn't work that way.

Comment: @Fred-ii- haha i knew it was something simple like that, as i wrote, after 15 lines i get blind... Big thanks for taking a look at it! i appreciate it!

Comment: hehe, you're welcome ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just make this a community wiki, since I didn't want to gain anything from this.

> *"?pageID and you're doing $_GET['pageNum']. I'd call that undefined... and probably relying on $pageNum. It doesn't work that way."*

---

> *"@Fred-ii- haha i knew it was something simple like that, as i wrote, after 15 lines i get blind... Big thanks for taking a look at it! i appreciate it! – per källström"*

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Then the rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: if i lets say want to show the highest number first on the page, now it shows 1 2 3 4 etc if i want like 5 4 3 2 1 instead, how would i approach that?

Comment: @perkällström You'd need to reverse the array http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php

Comment: yea i figured out that much, however im struggeling abit on getting it to do as i wish haha :(

Comment: @perkällström TBH, I'm not the best at dealing with arrays.

Comment: okey, thanks anyways.. and thanks again for the initial help :)